# Why does R sometimes sum numbers incorrectly?

Tags: r

Where X = c(0.07825,-0.08177,0.00352), the numbers in X should sum to 0.
Yet I get the following in R:

> sum(X)
>   4.77049e-18

when I should get 0.

To re-edit my question, I think I understand why R does it, but what to do about it? In my particular case I need to input a matrix to a function (which I did not formulate) where all the rows sum to 0, otherwise the function will produce an error. Is there any way around this without editing the function?

Comment: Floating point numbers are often relative, as in this case. That is a "very small number close to zero".

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/ This should be required reading for all programmers

Comment: `print(c(0.07825,-0.08177,0.00352), digits = 22)`

Comment: there's a slightly more R-centric version of the generic floating-point-precision answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Comment: It is not reasonable to expect a vector of double-precision floating point numbers to sum to exactly zero even if you try to enforce the requirement with, for example, `sum(X - mean(X)`. So I guess you need edit or re-write the function you are using.